# EPPLUS insert more than 1000 characters in cell value

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Is there a way to insert more than 1000 chars in cell value? Now it gets cut off.
Maybe is there a way to append values?

I couldn't find anything regarding this topic. I went trough all the options after `OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.Cell` and did not find anything. Right now I set the cell value like this:
`OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.Cell[A1].Value = 'something'` and something this 'something' exceed 1000 chars.

Comment: What are you storing there and which Excel version are you using? Excel allows up to 32K characters per cell but older versions can only display up to 1K. Newer versions don't have this limitation.

Comment: OH! I would have never came up with excel being a problem! Thank you very much! I will test with xlsx!

Comment: It's not the excel, bacuse I am already exporting to xlsx type of excel ...

Comment: What do you mean `test with xlsx`? That's the Excel file format, for the last 17 years. The old `xls` is obsolete for 17 years now and *doesn't* change how Excel itself displays data. If you used `xls` you were creating obsolete files that aren't supported even by Microsoft 365 or Google Sheets.  Which Excel version did you use?

Comment: Have you tried opening Excel on your machine and pasting text that's more than 1K characters in a cell? Are you able to view or edit it afterwards? If not, nothing Epplus does will fix this. If you use an old Excel version, an upgrade may fix this.

Comment: I am using excel 2017.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem and posted the actual code and screenshots. I don't have such an old Excel version. Have you tried with a fresh Excel version? Or with Excel online? EPPlus certainly works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce any problem. The following code using EPPlus 6.2 creates an Excel sheet with 4001 characters in C2, ending in `z`:

```
using OfficeOpenXml;

ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;

var file = new FileInfo("MyWorkbook.xlsx");
file.Delete();
using var package = new ExcelPackage(file);

var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Inventory");
//Add the headers
worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "ID";
worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Product";
worksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Notes";

//Add some items...
worksheet.Cells["A2"].Value = 12001;
worksheet.Cells["B2"].Value = "Nails";
worksheet.Cells["C2"].Value = new String('a',4000) + "z";

worksheet.Cells["C3"].Formula = "LEN(C2)";
package.Save();
```

[image: Screenshot of very long Excel cell shows the text overflowing to the right]

Trying to edit in-place shows all the characters, including the final `z` :

[image: In-place editing of very long cell shows all the characters in a very tall box]

Using the edit box may give the impression there aren't enough characters because the text is wrapped and `End` goes to the end of the line, not the end of the cell.

[image: Edit box after hitting End shows only the end of the first visible line]

`Ctrl+End` will go to the end of the cell though

[image: Edit box after hitting Ctrl+End shows the z character]

Comment: For some reason Trim() function was the problem. Don't ask me why, but that function somehow caused all the problems. I removed the Trim() and everything is working as it should.

Comment: There's no `Trim` in the question